# How to promote the site?

Tags: discussion, 7-essential, site-promotion

As the site comes into public beta, we should start to consider how to promote it amongst the relevant communities.

Comment: Robert Caitano's post is useful reading for this question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

Answer (score 4):

We can host a competition with some kind of prize (not sure what we can offer, whether something small like a library of the top 10 TCS books or a larger cash prize): solve one of the problems with more than 10 votes from this question: [Major unsolved problems in theoretical computer science?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/174/major-unsolved-problems-in-theoretical-computer-science).

Comment: that's pretty creative.

Comment: This is a nice idea.  I'd be glad to chip in towards a sponsored prize such as a library.  However, most of the top-voted problems are notoriously difficult (and independently prizeworthy) -- would it be better to pick out an open problem asked on the the site itself, with a better shot at being solved?

Comment: @Anand: Absolutely, I was thinking the same thing.  We would just need some way to classify what's a good but difficult question (sounds like a complexity problem...).

Answer (score 3):

I've used twitter and my blog (geomblog.blogspot.com) with some degree of success. I'll probably also request specific bloggers (the complexity blog, Dick Lipton etc) to advertise it as well.

**Update**: *Here are some specific examples of posts. I've tried to highlight certain posts from the main site that might catch people's eyes: I'll do this semi-regularly from now on.*

- [Latest news from the unnamed-but-working-on-it theoryCS Q&A site](http://geomblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/latest-news-from-unnamed-but-working-on.html)
- [cstheory Q&A site now open to the public !](http://geomblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/cstheory-q-site-now-open-to-public.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've sent out announcements on our internal mailing lists, and I'll pass it along to a few others in the near future.

I'll also give the site a mention in a few of my upcoming talks.  The site is a good example of new ways that the web can positively affect work in theory by speeding progress and letting us rapidly close or open new avenues of thinking, which certainly merits mention at the tail of a talk. This is doubly appropriate in cases where the site helps in investigating a problem.

Answer (score 2):

MO regulars could drop a note at meta.mathoverflow.net? The private beta was announced, but I haven't seen the public beta mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

There may be local user groups that are relevant to the subject (e.g. through meetup.com), which make a good place for promoting the site.  We can have "give-aways" (like tee-shirts with the site logo) at these events.

We can also sponsor some of the bigger conferences.

Comment: theory conferences are always happy for sponsorship :). A related idea might be to have a <insert name here> booth of some kind or a meetup at the conference. The next one coming up is FOCS in Las Vegas, in October.

Answer (score 2):

I think a nice way to bring in researchers in TCS to the site is adding a link to it on our academic websites.

Answer (score 2):

Advertise on DMANET?

Comment: that's a good idea. Maybe send out a short note pointing out the number of questions and users, and some sample questions that might highlight the technical aspects (i.e not big-list/CW questions)

Comment: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/383/highlights-of-cstheory-stackexchange-com